# Realtime Audio via USB Soundcard Possible?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I've installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 (using XFCE desktop) and using USB OTG cable, connected my M-Audio USB soundcard. My ambition is to be able to use Ardour on my Nexus 7 with the M-Audio soundcard (a perfect, portable sound studio). When plugging the M-Audio in, it is recognized by the system (so says dmesg) but it doesn't show up as an available soundcard in alsa-mixer.

It may just be that the usb-audio alsa module is not loaded, but until bluetooth keyboard is working it's a bit of a pain to investigate. Also, trying to use the jack sound server via qjackctl just throws errors about alsa and dbus.

Just wondering if anyone knows if it's viable at this early stage to at least get it all working, however buggy or if the possiblitly of this is a long way off at the moment?

With XFCE installed, the system runs nice and quick so once bluetooth keyboard is working it will be possible to have mouse/keyboard and a usable system so I'm hoping that professional audio will be an option on this device.

If there is anything I can do to help in getting this working, please let me know.

Comment: If you have the USB OTG cable, I recommend you connect it to a USB hub. Then you can use a USB keyboard/mouse to do further investigation. I'll ask our sound expert to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, we have not turned on the usb-audio module. I filed a bug requesting it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1073499